# Regex: find all of a given punctuation, only if key word exists

Tags: regex, bash, regexp-replace

Is it possible to find all punctuation marks of a given type, only when a key phrase exists?

For example:

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer pulvinar ac augue nec auctor. Vestibulum eleifend, sem non placerat porttitor, urna **neque** pulvinar enim, ut ullamcorper massa libero nec tellus. Sed est massa, congue eu auctor gravida, efficitur sit amet lacus. Nullam tincidunt posuere sollicitudin. Sed ac ullamcorper risus, ac cursus justo. Phasellus vehicula quam nec libero venenatis venenatis. Donec metus *erat:* maximus in risus *eu:* *imperdiet:* dignissim mauris. Aliquam sit amet augue vel ex tincidunt convallis. Morbi a sem **neque**. Nam tellus dolor, congue in mi eu, laoreet sodales lectus. Fusce sed ullamcorper purus. Nulla facilisi.

For above, as long as **"neque" is in the text**, I want to find all occurrences of `":"`

I've tried something like this without luck:

```
(.*\neque\b.*)(?!^)([:])
```

Comment: Does it have to be just one regex to do this? Is there any code involved?

Comment: what do you want to do with the `:`? count? see text before/after? replace with something? also, look for `:` anywhere in the text as long as `neque` exists, or only after?

Comment: Can you do it in two steps? 1) test if input has "neque" 2) find ":" ?

Comment: Are you doing it in bash?

Comment: @Klein Did my solution work for you?

Answer (score 0):

This works well in my system

explanation

1. extract the given phrase and store it in a variable.
2. if the phrase exists find the symbol and count its occurrences.

   ```
    #!/bin/bash

    a="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer pulvinar ac augue nec auctor. Vestibulum eleifend, sem non placerat porttitor, urna neque pulvinar enim, ut ullamcorper massa libero nec tellus. Sed est massa, congue eu auctor gravida, efficitur sit amet lacus. Nullam tincidunt posuere sollicitudin. Sed ac ullamcorper risus, ac cursus justo. Phasellus vehicula quam nec libero venenatis venenatis. Donec metus erat: maximus in risus eu: imperdiet: dignissim mauris. Aliquam sit amet augue vel ex tincidunt convallis. Morbi a sem neque. Nam tellus dolor, congue in mi eu, laoreet sodales lectus. Fusce sed ullamcorper purus. Nulla facilisi."

    b=$(echo "$a"| grep -o  "neque"| head -1)

    echo $b

    if [  "$b" ==  "neque" ]
    then
            number_of_occurences=$(echo "$a"| grep  -o ":"| wc -l)
            echo "$number_of_occurences"
    fi
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Your desired action is not clear. What I can read from the highlights in your example, you want to find all words that end in `:`, but only if the word `neque` exists anywhere in the text. Assuming that is the case, you can use this regex:

```
/(?=.*\bneque\b)\w+:/g
```

Explanation:

- `(?=.*\bneque\b)` - positive lookahead for `neque` with word boundaries, anywhere in the text; if this fails, the whole regex fails
- `\w+:` - look for a word that is followed by `:`
- use the `g` to find all occurrences of words followed by `:`

EDIT: After seeing that the `bash` tag has been added, here is a shell script version using a shortened string. The first example has the `neque` keyword, the second one not:

```
$ echo 'Urna neque metus erat: maximus in risus eu: imperdiet: dignissim.'\
> | egrep '\bneque\b' | egrep -o '\w+:'
erat:
eu:
imperdiet:
$
$ echo 'Urna metus erat: maximus in risus eu: imperdiet: dignissim.'\
> | egrep '\bneque\b' | egrep -o '\w+:'
$
```

Explanation:

- use first `egrep` to filter by required keyword `neque` using word boundaries
- use second 'egrep' with `-o` flag to extract words followed by `:`